# HDMI to DVI screen: computer won't remember connection

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I'm running Windows 10 on a machine that has an HDMI port, but no DVI, and I have linked it up to a second monitor that has a DVI port, but no HDMI, using a converter cable.

The problem is that, when Windows goes to sleep and then I wake it up, the computer usually "forgets" that it is connected to a second screen: in order to bring the second screen back, I have to unplug and reconnect the cable (sometimes twice).

This issue seems somehow related to HDMI-DVI compatibility: when I connect the two devices with a VGA cable (they both have VGA jacks built in), they never “forget” about each other. (However, the picture quality is far worse than with DVI, and my computer doesn't have screw-anchors in its VGA jack, so the cable is too easy to yank out by accident.)

Beyond that, though, I have no idea how to tackle this issue. Any suggestions?

Thanks